# Can I add a regular download link to Software Sources or 'sources.list'?

Tags: wine, ppa, software-sources

in software sources i see a lot of links that don't link to lanchpad.net

```
http://deb.playonlinux.com/ oreiric main
http://dl.google.com/linuxearth/deb/ stable main
http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu precise main
```

i was wondering: can i add a regular download link in my sources.list.
here is what i mean to do.
this is the download link for [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)(an example)

```
http://download.tuxfamily.org/notepadplus/6.1.3/npp.6.1.3.Installer.exe
```

i wonder can i add this(or an other) link to download the latest version of notepad++(or any software for that matter) and every time
there is a new version of notepad++ i can install the latest via update-manager. 
this is exactly when adding vlc(A example) in the sources.list. And when the software.
has been downloaded to run a command like `wine npp.6.1.3.Installer.exe /S /Silent`
for silent installation.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a wine installer/updater from within wine itself. Linux/Ubuntu/USC does not know what to do with exe and wine does ;)

Comment: is this an idea. i Have a website. If i create the same folder structure as a ppa archive and edit all the Release(.gpg). and link it to a notepad++.deb in the deb file is just an .exe . with a shell script to run wine notepad++.exe /S /Silent. or in the ppa link it to a shell script which downloads the setup.exe using wget commando. and runs wine notepad++.exe /S /Silent. might any of those work?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Software Sources file can only access Debian repositories and Debian style program installers.  Items on Launchpad, or the other sources you stated in your question are stored in a Debian repository on each location which contains items compatible with apt-get.

A regular download link, however, cannot be used in the software sources as an updateable item, especially for Windows files.

Answer (score 4):

The download links are *not* just any link but are the addresses of apt/debian repositories. If your specific software/program sets one up, you can add it but no, you can't add standard http links.

If you try to add them, and Software Sources lets you, that will break installs/updates on your system until you remove it.

Comment: He wants it for wine so yes those are windows installers ;)

Comment: The items for wine then are not compatible at all.  The question is tagged as wine, so I assume its *always* for Windows programs he's asking.  A crontab in userspace run daily might work, though...

Comment: Ah ok, mobile site shows no tags :(